# Extract an image url from a LI in an UL

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am trying to extract the href value `<img ng-src=` from the following HTML.

Where everything after `//images.mycar.com`... is dynamic.

It is a `<ul>` with many `<li>`, it will be the first item in the list. I want to be able to capture it so I can construct a URL to click on the image.

Sorry if my post is confusing .. i will try and clarify .

In the example `//images.mycar.com/BJ/11/BJ11TFZ/BJ11TFZ-used-FORD-FIESTA-DIESEL-HATCHBACK-1-6-TDCi-95-Titanium-3dr-Diesel-Manual-RED-2011-HR-S-01.jpg`

Is the item i want to extract, so i can then click on the image.

```
<!-- Begin Results List -->
  <ul id="resultsLists" class="o-media-list  c-animate  c-animate--show" ng-show="rc.results.vehicles.length" style="">
    <li id="BJ11TFZ" class="c-animate  c-animate--repeat  u-pb ng-scope" ng-repeat="car in rc.results.vehicles track by car.registration" style="">
      <div class="o-media  c-card  c-card--hover  c-card__block  u-p-0  u-shadowed  u-shadowed--hover">
        <div class="o-media__left  o-grid__col-sm-5  o-grid__col-xs-12  u-p-0  u-no-float--sm">

          <a ng-href="/used-car/FORD/FIESTA/BJ11TFZ" class="o-embed-responsive  o-embed-responsive--16by9  o-media__object  c-rollover" ng-click="rc.viewCar(car, $index)" href="/used-car/FORD/FIESTA/BJ11TFZ">
            <img ng-src="//images.mycar.com/BJ/11/BJ11TFZ/BJ11TFZ-used-FORD-FIESTA-DIESEL-HATCHBACK-1-6-TDCi-95-Titanium-3dr-Diesel-Manual-RED-2011-HR-S-01.jpg" alt="FORD FIESTA" class="o-embed-responsive__item  c-rollover__image" cs-src-responsive="[ [ 'small', '//images.mycar.com/BJ/11/BJ11TFZ/BJ11TFZ-used-FORD-FIESTA-DIESEL-HATCHBACK-1-6-TDCi-95-Titanium-3dr-Diesel-Manual-RED-2011-HR-M-01.jpg' ], [ 'retina', '//images.mycar.com/BJ/11/BJ11TFZ/BJ11TFZ-used-FORD-FIESTA-DIESEL-HATCHBACK-1-6-TDCi-95-Titanium-3dr-Diesel-Manual-RED-2011-HR-M-01.jpg' ] ]" src="//images.mycar.com/BJ/11/BJ11TFZ/BJ11TFZ-used-FORD-FIESTA-DIESEL-HATCHBACK-1-6-TDCi-95-Titanium-3dr-Diesel-Manual-RED-2011-HR-M-01.jpg">
          </a>
        </div>
```

Comment: what have you tried so far? also please dump everything below the closing a tag since all we want is the img src, this will make your example much more readable

Comment: yes, it can all be dumped after the image src path. I have update the snippet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract a href value from a Line Item list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47101078/extract-a-href-value-from-a-line-item-list)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right you are trying to extract this link below from the code above.

```
//images.mycar.com/BJ/11/BJ11TFZ/BJ11TFZ-used-FORD-FIESTA-DIESEL-HATCHBACK-1-6-TDCi-95-Titanium-3dr-Diesel-Manual-RED-2011-HR-S-01.jpg
```

That's simple enough. A pure javascript solution to this would be:

```
var imgUrl = document.getElementById("resultsLists").getElementsByTagName('img')[0].getAttribute('ng-src');
```

The code starts by selecting the main UL of the document. Then it selects the image itself. Then it gets the "ng-src" attribute of the image and saves it to the variable imgUrl.

Let me know if this is what you were trying to do.

Comment: OP asked for Java, not Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Okay bro, so in what's problem? If you need to use webdriver selenium and java 8
use next approach

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@id='resultsLists']/li//img")).stream()
.map(e -> e.getAttribute("ng-src"))
.collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Comment: That's going to get every IMG on the page

Answer (score -1):

You could get it like this below.

```
String href = driver.findElement(by.xpath("//ul/li/div/div/a")).getAttribute("href")
```

Comment: He doesn't want the `A` href, he wants the `IMG` src.

Comment: Quoting him-
I am trying to extract the href value <img ng-src= from the following HTML.

Comment: Yep... and the quote shows an `IMG` tag and `ng-src` that contains the URL (which he misspoke and stated `href`).